# ArcMap Flow Map lines get cut off

Tags: arcmap, flow-map

I am new to GIS and am doing a global flowmap using ArcMap 10.6.

The flow lines from East Asia/West Pacific to the NE USA should cut off in the mid-Pacific (on far right of map) but instead continue on to their destination converging outside of the map view. The flow lines instead of continuing in mid-Pacific on the far-left of the map towards their destination in the northeast USA, are not printed.

Here is an example of the type of problem I am having.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radial+flow+map%22++arcgis&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjrPKkj8PfAhW1HjQIHcRfCgAQ_AUIDigB&biw=992&bih=441#imgrc=AaWrYpun4yXTRM:

In the above example the lines converge outside the map view.

How do I make lines that go across the Pacific on the right of the map and wrap around the map and continue from the left of the map to their destination in the Northeast USA?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  To include pictures please use the Picture button rather than including external links.

Answer (score -1):

Try a KML format and insert it in Google Earth or insert a google earth base map. Also if you are interested only for the northen hemisphere try an azimuthal projection with an accordingly map.